# Why do charges exert more forces in gases than in liquids?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

While studying electrostatics my physics faculty told me that charges exert more force in gases than in liquids. I am not able to understand why exactly that's true.

While intuitively I have been able to make some sense of it, the mathematical modeling part completely eludes me. So, I would like an explanation if possible with some mathematical derivation and if possible some higher-order reading that I could do on that topic.

I am a High School Senior (Grade 12).

Edit: I wish to add more clarity to my question - "If two charged bodies are present in a gaseous medium, the Coulomb's force will be greater than if the bodies are in a liquid medium."  This was the exact statement said by my Physics faculty but he didn't elaborate upon the reason why this statement is true. So, I wish for a clear explanation.

Thank You!

Comment: Without more context, it's going to be difficult to answer your question.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: @DavidWhite Sorry edited it just now with, I hope, a much more clear context. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Coulomb force is determined with the formula $F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$, where $k=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$.  $\epsilon_0$ only applies in a vacuum, and all substances have a higher value of $\epsilon$ than $\epsilon_0$.  Since liquids have a higher value of $\epsilon$ than gases, it is seen that for the same charges on the spheres, separated by the same distance, the force of attraction or repulsion between the spheres is smaller in liquids than in gases.  For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity

Comment: Well, my question is What is the reason why the permittivity of liquids is greater than that of the gases?

Comment: The charge on the bodies in question polarizes the molecules that are around them.  That polarization decreases the measured strength of the electric field that surrounds those bodies, which decreases the force between them.  For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric